# Issue with setting background and UINavigationbar attributes swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, view

in my table view controller it works fine and I can configure the view like so:

```
func configureView() {

    self.tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background.jpg"))

    //set custom height for tableview row
    tableView.rowHeight = 64

    //change the font and size of nav bar text
    if let navBarFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 20.0) {
        let navBarAttributesDictionary: [String: AnyObject]? = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: navBarFont]

        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
    }
}
```

When I am trying to configure the view in another view controller (with the same navigation controller) it doesn't work and won't change the background or nav bar font, i use this configureview:

```
func configureView() {

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.jpg")!)

    //change the font and size of nav bar text
    if let navBarFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 20.0) {
        print("fired")

        let navBarAttributesDictionary: [String: AnyObject]? = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(), NSFontAttributeName: navBarFont]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navBarAttributesDictionary
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this or what could be going on? My first view controller is a table view, second a normal view. Thanks

Edit: my segue is of type Show, and my prepare for segue is as follows:

```
if segue.identifier == "showAlertInfoSegue" {
        if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? AlertViewController {

            viewController.tableAlert = nil
            //if the sender is the selected table view row - load in the data from the data struct
            if sender?.tag != 1 {
                viewController.tableAlert = alertDetail
            }

            viewController.onDataAvailable = {[weak self]
                (data) in
                if let weakSelf = self {
                    weakSelf.doSomethingWithData(data)
                }
            }
            viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        }
    }
```

I also see a peculiar grey shadow appearing on the top nav bar when transitioning, then it dissapears

Comment: your code works fine, how you are pushing in the stack navigation? Manually ? by segue ?

Comment: Hi, see the edit, it's a push segue, via the story board

Comment: Also, the navigation controller is also in a tab controller

Comment: @Ali_bean does your second view controller gets the same attributes that you set in your first view controller when it appears by push? your code seem fine, I suspect there is something with the hierarchy of your navigationController's viewControllers